# Remove "Google Code" from Careers profiles

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs

[image: Google Code]

Google Code should be removed at some point. Sunset schedule from [the Goog](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html):

> - March 12, 2015 - New project creation disabled.
> - August 24, 2015 - The site goes read-only. You can still checkout/view project source, issues, and wikis.
> - January 25, 2016 - The project hosting service is closed. You will be able to download a tarball of project source, issues, and wikis. These tarballs will be available throughout the rest of 2016.

It would be nice to provide a notice to users who have Google Code projects on their Careers profile, and provide a timeline for how long Careers will support Google Code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option to import Google Code projects is still being used occasionally (yes, even though it's now read only), so we're not going to remove it just yet.

We'll continue to link to Google Code projects on Careers profiles for as long as those URLs still work - it looks like as of 2016 they'll be redirected to the [Google Code Archive](https://code.google.com/archive/).

That said, usage of the import feature is *way* less than usage of the GitHub and BitBucket import options. To keep clutter down, we've moved the importer for Google Code projects to the "other..." link:

[image]

We moved the SourceForge and CodePlex importers there too, as they are also only used very rarely these days. (For some perspective, more GitHub projects have been added to Careers profiles in *the last 12 hours* than Google+CodePlex+SourceForge projects combined for *the whole of 2015 so far*).

Oh, as an added bonus we've also just added a [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/) importer, so you can now easily add any projects you have hosted there too. (This is for projects hosted on gitlab.com - for self-hosted GitLab you can continue to add a URL manually via the "other" link).

Comment: GitLab is an awesome addition. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Alex, please consider changing/removing the status tag from the post.

Comment: I am unable to change the status tag.